# A property of "function amplitude."

Tags: limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $P=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$ be a rectangle, $x\in P.$

> **Definition** Let $f:P\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function,then define the amplitude of function $f$ at the point $x$ as
>   $$\omega_f(x):=\lim_{r\to 0+}\sup\left\{|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|:\ x_1,x_2\in B(x,r)\cap P\right\}.$$
>   Here $B(x,r)$ represents the open ball centered at point $x$ with a radius of $r.$

If we define the function
$$B:P\to \mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto \lim_{r\to 0+}\sup_{a\in B(x,r)\cap P} f(a),$$
and function
$$A:P\to \mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto \lim_{r\to 0+}\inf_{a\in B(x,r)\cap P} f(a),$$
then we can see $$\omega_f(x)=B(x)-A(x),\ \forall\ x\in P.$$
So each interval $[A(x),B(x)]$ corresponds to the amplitude of function $f$ at the point $x$.

Define the Supremum and infimum of function $f$ as
 $$m:=\inf_{x\in P} f(x),\ M:=\sup_{x\in P} f(x),$$
then I can guess that there is
$$[m,M]\subset\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)].$$

In fact, I'm planning to use this conclusion to prove a theorem about Riemann integral(*$f$ is Riemann-integrable iff the region under its graph is Jordan-measurable*),but I meet great difficulties in proving this conclusion, since I don't have enough analytical techniques.

**Question**: Prove that $$[m,M]\subset\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)].$$
Any hint is also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I.** Show $[m,M] \supset \cup_x [A(x),B(x)]$

Take any $y\in \cup_x [A(x),B(x)]$. Then it must be in $[A(x),B(x)]$ for some $x$.

Hence, for any $y\in\cup_x [A(x),B(x)]$, there is an $x$ such that:
$$\inf_x f(x)\leq \lim_{r\rightarrow0}\inf_{z\in B_r(x)} f(z)\leq y \leq \lim_{r\rightarrow0}\sup_{z\in B_r(x)} f(z) \leq \sup_x f(x).$$

Thus $y\in[m,M]$.

So we have that  $[m,M] \supset \cup_x [A(x),B(x)].$

**II.** Show $[m,M] \subset \cup_x [A(x),B(x)]$

Assume that $y\in[m,M]$ and the contrary that $\forall x$ either $y<A(x)$ or $B(x)<y$. So we can partition $P$ into two subsets $X_a$ and $X_b$ where $y<A(x)$ for $x\in X_a$ and $B(x)<y$ for $x\in X_b$ with $P=X_a\cup X_b$.

We have that $m=\min\{ \inf_{X_a}f, \inf_{X_b} f \}$ and $M=\max\{ \sup_{X_a}f, \sup_{X_b} f \}$.

Assuming that neither $X_a$ nor $X_b$ is empty, we get that
$$m=\inf_{X_b}f\leq\sup_{X_b}f<y<\inf_{X_a}f \leq\sup_{X_a}f =M$$

But $P$ is connected so we can find $z\in\overline{X}_b\cap X_b$ (without loss of generality) such that $B_r(z)\cap X_a \neq \emptyset$ and $B_r(z)\cap X_b \neq \emptyset$ for all $r$. I.e. one of the partition sets contains a point on its "inner boundary" with the other partition set. This implies that $A(z)\leq \sup_{X_b} f$ and that $\inf_{X_a} f \leq B(z)$.

So we conclude that $y\in[A(z), B(z)]$ which is a contradiction.

If either $X_a$ or $X_b$ is empty, then the result changes slightly. I'll assume $X_a=\emptyset$ without loss of generality.

$$M=\sup_{X_b}f<y$$

Thus $y\notin [m,M]$, a contradiction.

The conclusion is that $[m,M] = \cup_x [A(x),B(x)]$.

Comment: Emmmm,since $m=\min\left\{\inf_{X_a} f,\inf_{X_b} f\right\},$ I think that$$y<\inf_{X_a} f \ \text{and}\  y\geqslant \inf_{X_b} f \nRightarrow y<m.$$

Comment: Ya, it's definitely contradictory, which is what we want, but not sure if it's good enough. The argument might be able to be cleaned up, but maybe wholly faulty. I'll think about it.

Comment: I think this argument can be repaired by using the connectedness of $\mathbb R^n$. Or maybe the entire argument can be discarded and just use connectedness more directly.

Comment: Well, today I've also thought of that, and have obtained a proof using the connectedness of  rectangle. In fact, $P$ could be any connected space, and the conclusion is still correct. Form the connectness of $P$ we can conclude that $\overline{X_a}\cap\overline{X_b}\neq \emptyset.$ Choose a point $x_0$ from this intersection, then we can prove that $y\in [A_{x_0},B_{x_0}],$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I'll edit my answer later, but it sounds like you are good to go now.

Comment: @jods: I find that the present proof is still incomplete. In fact, we need to ensure that $X_a\neq \emptyset\ \text{and}\  X_b\neq \emptyset,$ which is a essential  detail. If we assume that $y\in (m,M),$  we can see that this is true, so the present proof still work, but can only prove that $$\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)]\supset (m,M).$$

Comment: And using the compactness of $P$ we can prove that

Comment: $\left\{m,M\right\}\subset \bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)].$ In fact, we can see $A$ is lower semicontinuous, and $B$  is upper semicontinuous. And there's a theorem saying that **If C is a compact space (for instance a closed, bounded interval [a, b]) and f : C → \mathbb{R} is upper semi-continuous, then f has a maximum on C, and if f : C → \mathbb{R} is lower semi-continuous, then f has a minimum on C.** So when $P$ is compact we have $\left\{m,M\right\}\subset \bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)].$

Comment: @painday, That probably works too, but I am not as familiar with semi-continuity. I don't see how the result follows immediately without a little more explanation. I'll think about it. You could consider writing up and posting your solution using semicontinuity and compactness. I think having multiple solutions is good. It's generally ok to post an answer for your own question too.

If $X_a$ or $X_b$ is empty, then it does change my argument slightly, and I will fix that now.

Comment: :OK, I'll write my solution tomorrow :).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @jdods, finally I obtain the following theorem:

> **Theorem**: Let $(P,\mathcal{T})$ be a connected topology space, and $f:P\to \mathbb{R}$  be a bounded function, define
>   $$m:=\inf_{x\in P} f(x),\ M:=\sup_{x\in P} f(x),$$
>   and define functions
>   $$A:P\to \mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto \sup_{\text{$U$ is a open neighborhood of $x$}} \big[\inf_{a\in U} f(a)\big],$$
>   $$B:P\to \mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto \inf_{\text{$U$ is a open neighborhood of $x$}} \big[\sup_{a\in U} f(a)\big],$$
>   then we have
>   $$(m,M)\subset\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)]\subset [m,M].\ (*)$$
>   And if topology space $(P,\mathcal{T})$ is also compact, then we have
>   $$\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)]=[m,M].\ (**)$$

**Proof of $(*)$:** It's obvious that $\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)]\subset [m,M].$
Let's prove that $(m,M)\subset \bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)].$

For arbitrary $y\in (m,M),$ if we suppose that $y\notin \displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in D}[A(x),B(x)],$ 
then we have $$y\in (-\infty,A(x)]\cup[B(x),+\infty),\ \forall\ x\in X.$$

Define sets $$X_a:=\left\{x\in X| y< A(x)\right\},\ X_b:=\left\{x\in X| y> B(x)\right\},$$
then $P=X_a\cup X_b.$ Let's prove that $X_a,X_b\neq \emptyset.$

In fact, if $X_a=\emptyset,$ then $P=X_{b},$ thus $y\geqslant B(x),\ \forall\ x\in P.$

But $$B(x)\geqslant f(x),\ \forall\ x\in X,$$
thus $y\geqslant f(x),\ \forall\ x\in X,$ so $y\geqslant M,$ which is a contradiction.
Now we see that $X_a\neq \emptyset,$ and similarly we can prove $X_b\neq \emptyset.$

Since $X_a\cup X_b=X,$ and $X_a, X_b\neq \emptyset,$ thus we have $\overline{X_a},\overline{X_b}\neq \emptyset,$ and $\overline{X_a}\cup \overline{X_b}=X.$ From the connectness of $P$ we infer that $\overline{X_a}\cap \overline{X_b}\neq \emptyset.$

Take $x_0\in \overline{X_a}\cap \overline{X_b},$ and assume that $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0,$ then we have $(U\cap \overline{X_a})\neq \emptyset,\ (U\cap \overline{X_b})\neq \emptyset.$ Take $x_1\in (U\cap \overline{X_a}),\ x_2\in (U\cap \overline{X_b}),$ then $U$ is  an open neighborhood of  both $x_1$ and $x_2.$ Thus
$$\inf_{a\in U} f(a)\leqslant A(x_2),\ B(x_1)\leqslant \sup_{a\in U} f(a).$$
Notice that $$A(x_2)\leqslant B(x_2)< y<A(x_1)\leqslant B(x_1),$$

we have
$$\inf_{a\in U} f(a)<y<\sup_{a\in U} f(a). $$
From the arbitrariness of $U$ we infer that
$$A(x_0)\leqslant y\leqslant B(x_0),$$
which is a contradiction.

So now we've proved that
$$(m,M)\subset\bigcup_{x\in P} [A(x),B(x)]\subset [m,M].\ (*)$$

To prove $(**)$,the second part of the theorem, we need to prove some useful propositions first:

> **Definition 1**：Let $X$ be a topology space,，$x_0\in X,$ $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function. If  $\forall\ \varepsilon>0,$  $\ \exists $ an open neighborhood of $x_0$,denoted as $U,$ such that
>   $$f(x)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon,\ \forall\ x\in U,$$
>    then we say function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous at point $x_0$. If function $f$ is  upper semi-continuous  at every point in $X$ , then we say  $f$ is upper semi-continuous function.

Similarly, If  $\forall\ \varepsilon>0,$  $\ \exists $ an open neighborhood of $x_0$,denoted as $U,$ such that
$$f(x)>f(x_0)-\varepsilon,\ \forall\ x\in U,$$
 then we say function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is lower semi-continuous at point $x_0$. If function $f$ is  lower semi-continuous  at every point in $X$ , then we say  $f$ is lower semi-continuous function.

We can see that if both $f$ and $g$ are upper semi-continuous, then function $f+g,$ is also upper semi-continuous, function $-f$ is lower semi-continuous.  And if  upper semi-continuousfunction $f$ is always negative on $X$ or always positive on $X,$ then function $1\over{f}$ is lower semi-continuous.

Now we define a set as
$$T:=\left\{(-\infty,a)|\ a\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\cup \left\{\mathbb{R}\right\}\cup \left\{\emptyset\right\},$$
then we can see $T$  is a topology on $\mathbb{R},$ and the following definition is equivalent to definition 1:

> **Definition 2**: Let $X$ be a topology space, $x_0\in X,$ $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function. If map $f:X\to (\mathbb{R}，T)$ is continuous at point $x_0,$ then we say function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous at point $x_0$. If map $f:X\to (\mathbb{R}，T)$ is continuous , then we say function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous.

The following lemma is important:

**Lemma:** If topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is compact, and function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous, then $f$ is bounded above, and $f$ has a maximum on $X.$

**Proof:**
  Define set
$$X_n:=\left\{x\in X|\ f(x)<n\right\},$$
here $n\in \mathbb{N},$ then  $X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} X_n,$  and according to Definition 2,  $X_{n}$ is open set in $X.$ From the compactness of $X$ we can see there exist $n_1,\cdots,n_k,$ such that 
$$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^k X_{n_i}.$$ Let
$M'=\displaystyle\max\left\{n_1,\cdots,n_k\right\},$
then $X=X_{M'},$ thus $f(x)<M',\ \forall\ x\in X,$ so $f$ is bounded above.

Now let's prove that if upper semi-continuous function $f$ is bounded above, then $f$ has a maximum $X$.

In fact, suppose that $f$ has no maximum, then define $K:=\sup_{x\in X} f(x),$
we can see function $g:={1\over{K-f}}:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous, thus $g$ is bounded above. Let $M$ be a upper bound of $g$, then $$g(x)={1\over{K-f(x)}}\leqslant M,\ \forall\ x\in X.$$ Notice that $g(x)>0,\ \forall\ x\in X,$ so $M>0,$ thus
$$K-f(x)\geqslant {1\over{M}},\ \forall\ x\in X,$$
i.e.
$$f(x)\leqslant K-{1\over{M}},\ \forall\ x\in X,$$
which is a contradiction. **Q.E.D**

Similarly,If topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is compact, and function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is lower semi-continuous, then $f$ is bounded below, and $f$ has a minimum on $X.$

Now let's complete the proof of the theorem:

**Proof of $(**)$:** First we'll prove that function $B(x)$ is upper semi-continuous, and function $A(x)$ is lower semi-continuous.

In fact, according to the definition of $B(x),$ for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists  an open neighborhood of $x,$ such that
$$\sup_{a\in U} f(a)<B(x)+\varepsilon.$$
Then assume that $t\in U,$ then $U$ is also an
open neighborhood of $t,$ so
$$B(t)\leqslant \sup_{a\in U} f(a).$$
Now we see that
$$B(t)<B(x)+\varepsilon,\ \forall\ t\in U.$$ 
Thus function $B(x)$ is upper semi-continuous.
Similarly we can prove that function $A(x)$ is lower semi-continuous.

Now notice that
$$\sup_{x\in P} B(x)=M, \ \inf_{x\in P} A(x)=m,$$ and since $P$ is compact,
according to the lemma we have 
$$m\in \bigcup_{x\in P} \left\{A(x)\right\},\ M\in \bigcup_{x\in P} \left\{B(x)\right\}.$$
**Q.E.D**